# How to show in console?

Tags: objective-c

I need to show a square with number of edge is entered from keyboarded.

I wrote as C++. It's OK.
[image]

But as Objectvive C. It's not OK.
[image]

Please help me. How to fix it.

Comment: can you edit your question to show the code you're using for C++ and Objectvive C ?

Comment: you need to post the code that you have tried and then ask for help

Comment: Thank you! I printed it.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell that you printed every `*` with a separate call to `NSLog`. Don't use `NSLog` if you need precise control over the format of the output.

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you have the entire C standard library available in your Objective-C program. Just use `printf` or `puts` or `putchar` to print your square.

Comment: Thank you very much! I printed it. I used  printf ("*\n") but now I use 2 commands printf("*) and printf ("\n). I work well. Thank you very much. (^__^).